# Tomato bisque soup too sweet

Tags: sugar, soup

I was making this tomato bisque and the recipe called for 1 cup sugar so I thought I added 1 cup of sugar. But what I added was 1 cup of truvia, an artificial sweetener so my 1 cup of sugar is really 2 cups of sugar. I have added 3 cans more of diced tomatoes plus some dill, even a can of tomato sauce. There is 1 quart of half and half and 1 quart of heavy cream. How can I salvage the soup?

Comment: Adjust your ratios for the other ingredients?

Comment: Sugar in something like this is not just for sweetness for a start. I'd recommend in future of you insist on using stevia to add it at the end like you would with salt. Tasting as you add. Literally all the stevia is doing, is sweetening. As long as it dissolves there is no benefit gained by adding at the start.